# Ternary operator issue in Guava: cannot convert from Ordering<Comparable> to Ordering<String>

Tags: java, java-7, guava, ternary-operator

I just met this weird condition with Guava's Ordering class.

With this code using ternary operator:

```
Ordering<String> ordering = flag ? Ordering.natural().nullsFirst() : Ordering.natural().nullsLast();
```

Note: `flag` is boolean variable.

I got this error shown in Eclipse for that line:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Ordering<Comparable> to Ordering<String>
```

But if I change it to if-else block, no error found.

```
    Ordering<String> ordering;
    if (flag) {
        ordering = Ordering.natural().nullsFirst();
    }
    else {
        ordering = Ordering.natural().nullsLast();
    }
```

Anyone can explain what happened here?

Note: I'm using java 7.

Comment: This is a limitation of generic type inference in Java 7. Upgrade to 8 and you will be fine. If you can't, use explicit type arguments or use the `if` solution.

Comment: Could you describe more detail about the limitation? If I change it to `Ordering<Comparable>`, the error is gone but the warning "Comparable is a raw type. References to generic type Comparable<T> should be parameterized" will show up. Then if I change it to `Ordering<Comparable<String>>`, the error comes back <:o)

Comment: You just need to specify explicit types to the generic methods. The Java 7 compiler cannot work out what you want.

Comment: `Ordering<String> ordering = flag ? Ordering.<String>natural().nullsFirst() : Ordering.<String>natural().nullsLast();`

Comment: You could just have your `ordering` be of type `Ordering<? super String>`...

Comment: @JBNizet: huh? that's weird syntax

Comment: @suud: That's the syntax for invoking a generic method with a specific (not inferred) type argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
Ordering<String> ordering = flag ? Ordering.natural().nullsFirst() : Ordering.natural().nullsLast();
```

to:

```
Ordering<String> ordering = flag ? Ordering.<String>natural().nullsFirst() : Ordering.<String>natural().nullsLast();
```

This works because it tells the Java compiler that the `<C>` in the `natural` method declaration should be `String`. Here's the method declaration in Guava's `Ordering` class for `natural`:

```
public static <C extends Comparable> Ordering<C> natural()
```

By calling `Ordering.<String>natural()`, you're explicitly declaring `<C>` to be `<String>`.

Note that this works for any method that has the type declared as part of the method declaration, like nearly all the static methods in `Collections`.